# How does this while block work?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
var result = 1
var counter = 0
while (counter < 10) {
     result = result * 2
     counter += 1
};

console.log(result);
```

I am confused how does counter update result here? We are increasing counter by 1 but how does that affect the result?

Can someone please dumb it down to me? I am new to programming.

Edit : I know this question has been asked many times. I searched through many answers but didn't get the info I required. I have a very specific doubt and wanted to clarify it so please go easy on that down button. :)

[Solved]

Same code with for loop.

```
var result = 1
for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
  result *= 2;
};
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Did you see this line? `result = result*2`

Comment: `counter` does not affect `result`, it is used to control the loop. Each time through the loop `result`  is multiplied by 2, then that result is used as `result` the next time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` and `counter` are separate variables with different goals in this code.

`counter` is incremented like

```
counter += 1
```

so that eventually the `while` condition

```
while (counter<10)
```

will be satisfied and the code will cease to execute.

As for `result`, each time the code in the while block is executed, `result` is updated by multiplying by 2.

```
result = result*2
```

It is 'updated' because the variable `result` was initialized outside the `while` loop but is accessible by it. With the above statement, it is taking the existing `result` variable and multiplying it by 2 then storing it back in `result`.

Comment: Hey, I want to know how result works? As far as I understand, it goes like this :
In first turn it results 2 but since the condition is true, it reiterates again but this time it moves on from 2 and gives 4. The condition is still true and thus it gives 8 then 16 and finally 1024. But how does it give exponents of 2? Does it store the value and when it reiterates, multiplies that value by 2? Like after 1st turn it stores 2 and in second turn multiples 2*2 and stores 4 for next turn. In the next turn 4*2 and then stores 8 for next turn. This keeps on happening till condition becomes false which

Comment: is at 10th turn (or when counter value is 9) and it finally gives me the last stored value which happens to be 1024. Is my reasoning correct? :)

Comment: @MarineBiologist, yes, you seem to be on the right path. See my updated answer at the end regarding the result variable.

Comment: Understood, thanks. So this won't work if result was a local variable instead of global?

Comment: Yes, if it was local, then each time the result variable would be 're-initialized' and would always be '2'. To be clear, local would mean if the result variable was initialized inside the while loop.

Comment: Ahh, that was the main confusion. Differentiating when it gives 1024 and when 2. I think I have a better grasp of it now, thanks mate!

Comment: The same goes for "for" loop as well, right? I have to declare result as a global variable and put counter as the argument? I will edit the question and put for loop as well. Can you tell me whether it is correct? :)

Comment: @MarineBiologist, yes! Exactly! That for loop is the exact replica of the while loop

Comment: By the way, sorry you had to endure being down-voted like that. Some people just don't understand we were all beginners once. Keep your head up! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I understand that it is annoying for people to see the same questions every now and then and they do it out of frustration or to promote fresh content but I had a very specific doubt which wasn't solved by googling the question so I asked it. I'm happy that I understood the working of the code so I don't mind the downvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

You mean this:

```
loop | counter |  result  | counter < 10
  1       1          2           yes
  2       2          4           yes
  3       3          8           yes
  4       4          16          yes
  5       5          32          yes
  6       6          64          yes
  7       7          128         yes
  8       8          256         yes
  9       9          512         yes
  10      10         1024        no end of loop


  console.log(result);   ->    1024
```